# System.InvalidOperationException: Can't replace active reader in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

My .Net 6 application was working without any problems but recently whenever the load increases we see this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't replace active reader

I have investigated a lot on this issue , but could not find a solution. Can someone help on this please?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Can't replace active reader.
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.SetActiveReader(MySqlDataReader dataReader) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 874
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 460
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 344
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 337
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: We have no idea what your code looks like, which makes it hard to help. If you could provide a [mcve] that would help enormously.

Comment: Does this [Github issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1154)  related to your problem? Do you use latest `MySqlConnector`?

Answer (score 1):

There's not even close to enough info here to accurately diagnose this. However, I've seen three common issues causing similar behavior:

1. The app uses a data access pattern that tries to preserve the same connection object throughout the app. This is a bad idea. Each query should get it's own new connection object. Really. Ideally the connection will be created with a `using` block.
2. The app calls `connection.Close()` instead of disposing connections as part of a `finally` section after a `try` block or with a `using` block. This potentially leaves connections hanging open when there are exceptions (possibly even handled exceptions), and under load these hanging connections can exhaust the connection pool on either the clients or the server. Again, the solution is `using` blocks.
3. You're already doing the other things right, but the load really is so high the connection pool is becoming exhausted just from normal use (this is *extremely rare*!). In that case, the solution is to be even more aggressive with opening the `using` blocks later and closing them earlier, start being more efficient with the connections (ie: you can run more than one SQL statement in the same `Execute__()` call), and explore adjusting the pool size.

I know the error message references a reader rather than a connection, but all of these can lead to trying to run a new query and associate the result with a connection while another reader on the connection is still active, because a prior connection in the pool wasn't finished. But again: there's nothing like enough info in the question to accurately diagnose this.